# Adding a field mapping to 'base64Encode' an index field by calling REST endpoint not working: "A resource without a type name was found"

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I'm trying to update a search index (using the [Update Indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/Update-Indexer)) by sending a PUT request to `https://searchservicename.search.windows.net/indexes/indexName?api-version=2017-11-11` and it's not working.

If I make the exact same request with the list of fields, the request works as expected and I receive a 200.  As soon as I try to add `fieldMappings` as well, I get an error.

My Json I'm adding to the request as "application/json":

```
{
  "name": "indexName",
  "fields": [
    <List of Valid Fields w/ Valid Types>
  ],
  "fieldMappings": [
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "fieldName",
      "targetFieldName": "fieldName",
      "mappingFunction": {
        "name": "base64Encode"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

When calling the API, the error I'm getting is:

```
{Search request failed: {"error":{"code":"","message":"The request is invalid. Details: index : A resource without a type name was found, but no expected type was specified. To allow entries without type information, the expected type must also be specified when the model is specified.\r\n"}}
```

I expect the request to return 200 and have the field mapping added.

The error I get seems to be related to the list of fields but as mentioned before, the request works as expected with the same body minus the field mappings.

Let me know if you need any other information from me - Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Field mappings should be added to an indexer, not an index. Based on your request, you are trying to update an index.

Comment: Ahh, thank you.  I knew it had to be something obvious I was missing.  Going to look into indexers now